# setup.py in my project skeleton directory...oh the misery

Tags: python, setuptools, nose, setup.py

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I have two issues:

1) When I cd to the directory above 'tests' to run 'nosetests' it runs 0 tests (should be 1).

2) I can't get the script in \bin to be added by setup.py

My setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    "description": "project skeleton testing",
    "author": "David",
    "url": "https://github.com/dmt257/learnpythonSkeletonDirectory",
    "download_url": "https://github.com/dmt257/learnpythonSkeletonDirectory/archive/0.1.zip",
    "author_email": "dmt257257@gmail.com",
    "version": "0.1.5",
    "install_requires": ["nose"],
    "packages": ["usethistest_main", "tests"],
    "scripts": ["/bin/ask_script.py"],
    "name": "usethistest"
}

setup(**config)
```

Directory:

```
Directory: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\projects\usethistest


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       29/08/2016     12:41                .git
d-----       29/08/2016     12:41                bin
d-----       29/08/2016     13:15                dist
d-----       29/08/2016     12:41                docs
d-----       29/08/2016     13:08                tests
d-----       29/08/2016     13:14                usethistest.egg-info
d-----       29/08/2016     12:41                usethistest_main
-a----       22/08/2016     09:22              5 README.txt
-a----       29/08/2016     13:09            573 setup.py
```

Package 'tests':

```
Directory: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\projects\usethistest\tests


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       29/08/2016     13:06            166 usethistest_main
-a----       16/08/2016     16:05              0 __init__.py
-a----       29/08/2016     13:08            147 __init__.pyc
```

'usethistest_main':

```
from nose.tools import*
import usethistest_main

def setup():
    print("SETUP!")

def teardown():
    print("TEAR DOWN!")

def test_basic():
    print("I RAN!")
```

The package 'usethistest_main':

```
    Directory: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\projects\usethistest\usethistest_main


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       24/08/2016     11:33            960 question.py
-a----       16/08/2016     16:05              0 __init__.py
-a----       24/08/2016     09:06            147 __init__.pyc
```

'\bin' has a single script named 'ask_script.py.

I've spent so much time on this it's ridiculous. I obviously haven't a clue.

Comment: Try changing scripts to:

"scripts": ["./bin/ask_script.py"],

or
"scripts": ["bin/ask_script.py"],

Comment: don't use scripts, add the code to your actual codebase and use the `entrypoints` option.

Comment: thanks. Will give it a try.